# How to use iregex with ORM filter in Django?

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

Model

```
class A(models.Model):
   t = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True) // X250630-1001axc
```

Database: **Mysql**

I tried this, but the result queryset is empty. I went to the official documentation, but nothing helped.

```
A.objects.filter(t__iregex=r'X\d{6}-\d{4}[\da-z]{,3}')
```

I thought my regex was wrong, but it worked through `re.search`

Comment: Should you be usig `[a-z]{,3}` instead of `[\da-z]{,3}`?

Comment: @RedCricket This is the case `X250630-1001ax1`

Answer (score 0):

The quantifier `{,3}` is not supported by all regex flavor. Use `{0,3}` or `{1,3}` instead.

```
A.objects.filter(t__iregex=r'X\d{6}-\d{4}[\da-z]{0,3}')
```